# Bigcommerce Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, magento, bigcommerce

I am referencing this: https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-ruby/blob/master/examples/products/product.rb

Here is the code:

```
# List products
@products = Bigcommerce::Product.all
puts @products

# Get a product
@product = @products[0]
puts Bigcommerce::Product.find(@product.id)
```

I understand the #list products, but it appears that #get a product is just pulling the first item in the array @products and displaying it?

I don't understand this: `Bigcommerce::Product.find(@product.id)`

End goal is to search @products for a specific property value. Like where SKU = some SKU or title = some time or price = some price, etc.

Also, is @products a hash or an array?

So confused. :(

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the #list products, but it appears that #get a product is
>   just pulling the first item in the array @products and displaying it?

Yes. It seems like just an example.

> I don't understand this: Bigcommerce::Product.find(@product.id)

This returns a `Product` object with `id == @product.id`.

> Also, is @products a hash or an array?

It is an array. See the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/all/class) for ActiveRecord's all method.

**EDIT** In this API, [SKU](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-ruby/blob/master/lib/bigcommerce/resources/products/sku.rb) and Product are different resources (see product-related resources [here](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-ruby/tree/master/lib/bigcommerce/resources/products)). To search by SKU, you should do this:

```
# Get a product sku
puts Bigcommerce::Sku.find(@product.id, @sku.id)
```

See the [example](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-ruby/blob/master/examples/products/sku.rb). SKUs contain a reference to their Product, so you can search by SKU and then get the Product you want.

**EDIT 2** Bear in mind that [Resources](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-ruby/blob/master/lib/bigcommerce/resources/resource.rb) in this API are subclasses of [Hashie::Trash](https://github.com/intridea/hashie), *not ActiveRecord* which would be more usual, so we can't rely on things like find_by.

Comment: can you explain 'This returns a Product object with id == @product.id? For example, how would I return a product where sku = '100011'?

Comment: Bigcommerce::Product.find_by(sku: '100011')

Comment: David, here is what I get when I try that: undefined method `find_by' for Bigcommerce::Product:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: @LanterneRouge David very reasonably assumed that `Product` extended ActiveRecord, which has a method called [find_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by). However, this is not the case, thus `Product` has no `find_by` method, resulting in the error you posted.

Comment: @LanterneRouge I edited my answer to address your question about searching a Product by SKU. Tldr: they are two different resources.

Comment: @brito thank you! can you give a specific code example of how I find a specific sku and return the product? I am a visual learner.

Comment: @brito what exactly do I put for '@product.id' and '@sku.id'?

Answer (score 1):

@products looks like it should be a collection of instances of Bigcommerce::Product. Based on that, @product = @products[0] assigns to @product the first of the collection.

I do not understand:

```
puts Bigcommerce::Product.find(@product.id)
```

I would think that this would suffice:

```
puts @product
```